# How to specify data type for hashtable?

Tags: powershell, types, hashtable, int32

It seems PowerShell hashtable (`@{}`) is map of string→string by default. But I wish that my value type is `Int32` so that I could do calculation on it.

How could I specify the type information when declaring a hashtable variable?

Comment: If you assign the value as an int, the hashtable value is still an int: $test = @{ "myValue" = 3 }; $test.myValue | gm

Comment: Show us an example of what you are doing and we will explain it. You can have it both ways. Values can be "cast" during comparsion. It all depends on what is on the left hand side of the comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hashtables map keys to values. The type of the keys and values is immaterial.

```
PS C:\> $ht = @{}
PS C:\> $ht[1] = 'foo'
PS C:\> $ht['2'] = 42
PS C:\> $ht

Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              42
1                              foo

PS C:\> $fmt = "{0} [{1}]`t-> {2} [{3}]"
PS C:\> $ht.Keys | % {$fmt -f $_, $_.GetType().Name, $ht[$_], $ht[$_].GetType().Name}
2 [String]      -> 42 [Int32]
1 [Int32]       -> foo [String]
```

If you have an integer in a string and want to assign that as an integer, you can simply cast it on assignment:

```
PS C:\> $ht[3] = [int]'23'
PS C:\> $ht.Keys | % {$fmt -f $_, $_.GetType().Name, $ht[$_], $ht[$_].GetType().Name}
2 [String]      -> 42 [Int32]
3 [Int32]       -> 23 [Int32]
1 [Int32]       -> foo [String]
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative to `Hashtable` is the [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) which allows to explicitly specify type of key and value.

In the following, a dictionary with `string` key and `int` value will be created:

```sh
[Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, int]] $dict = @{}
    
$dict['a'] = 42      # Ok
$dict['b'] = '42'    # Ok (implicit type conversion)
$dict['c'] = 'abc'   # Error: Cannot convert value "abc" to type "System.Int32"
```

Note that a `Dictionary` created this way has **case-sensitive keys**, contrary to a `Hashtable`, whose keys are case-insensitive.

```
$dict['a'] = 42
$dict['A'] = 21  # Creates a 2nd entry!
```

To make the `Dictionary` **case-insensitive** like a `Hashtable`, it must be created differently, by passing a [`StringComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer?view=net-6.0) to the `Dictionary` constructor:

```sh
$dict = [Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, int]]::new( [StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase )
$dict['a'] = 42
$dict['A'] = 21  # Overwrites the entry whose key is 'a'
```